# HTML5 video inside bootstrap modal window renders very incorrectly when in "full screen" mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, html5-video, fullscreen

I have an HTML5 video that displays inside a bootstrap modal dialog. The video plays fine in normal mode, but when the fullscreen button is clicked, the video displays, for lack of a better description, ALL OUT OF WACK.

Most of the video is hidden and only a small square (smaller than the original video tag size) is shown.

Does anyone know what the issue might be or how I could get this to display properly?

Comment: I have the same issue. iOS (apparently any version) using Kaltura's HTML5 player. The video does not escape some element on the page which is roughly the same size as the modal.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred in my current project, but only on iPad. Fullscreen worked fine on any other devices. I am using AngularJS and ui-bootstrap to show the modals.

Even adapting the example from http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/tests/BootstrapModal.html wasn't possible, I just didn't find the place where to change anything in the HTML/CSS structure to get it working on my iPad (mini).

The solution for me was to add the following flashvars param to my `kWidget.embed` settings:

```
...
"flashvars":  {
    ...
    "EmbedPlayer.EnableIpadHTMLControls" : false,
    ...
},...
```

With this configuration, fullscreen works on iPad, behaviour on other devices stays unchanged.